# delete double 0 from 1st char until found a first number

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a problem with these numbers:

> 000000000480000.00
>
> 000000001300000.00
>
> 000000000300500.00
>
> 000004000300500.00

How can I remove duplicate 0s until the first numbers 1-9 are found to become:

> 480000.00
>
> 1300000.00
>
> 300500.00
>
> 4000300500.00

I need a `preg_replace()` function in PHP.

Comment: surely ltrim() with a charlist of '0' is the easiest option

Answer (score 1):

```
$number = preg_replace("#^0{0,}#", "", $number);
```

This removes all the first zeroes from the string.

There is also a solution with `ltrim()`:

```
$number = ltrim($number, '0');
```

Comment: Both of your solutions are appropriate. However, the second is a significantly quicker and less CPU-hungry solution.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Yeah. The first solution is only there because the TO wanted one with `preg_replace()`.

Comment: I know, I'm only stating the performance increase for the TO's benefit :-)